# trying to build insert rows function in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to develop a function that will insert rows into a database in sqlite3 for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql
import os
sea_level_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\SeaLevel.csv", skiprows=3)
display(sea_level_df)
conn = sql.connect(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\sqlite\db\z.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
sea_level_df.to_sql('v', conn)
class database:

     def __init__(self):
        conn = sql.connect('z')
        cur = conn.cursor()

     def create_table():
        n = """CREATE TABLE e( 
        YEAR INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        SEA_LEVEL INTEGER NOT NULL)
        ;"""
        cur.execute(n)
        print("table created")
        conn.close()

     def insert(query,tup):
        conn = sql.connect('z')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, tup)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
```

When I run the code above and try to call the function by going

```
database.insert(2022, -17.89)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [161], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 database.insert(2022,-17.89)

Input In [157], in database.insert(query, tup)
     17 conn = sql.connect('z')
     18 cursor = conn.cursor()
---> 19 cursor.execute(query, tup)
     20 print("Search query: ",query)
     21 sqliteConnection.commit()

TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not int
```

Comment: this is just error in your SQL ... the syntax should be `UPDATE <table name> SET <column name> = <value>`  but you have `UPDATE z`. What is `z`?  The table name is `e`.  You want something like `UPDATE e SET YEAR = ?`

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need a class (and as it is, you're missing a `self` parameter, so calling that method on an instance of the class wouldn't work).
2. You can (and should) reuse the `conn` you have in the outer scope (or just pass it in to the function).

   - On that note, `sqlite3.connect('z')` would create a database file called `z`, which is not what you want.
3. The table name in your example is `v`, not `z`.
4. There is no identifier `e` in the SQL query, so that's not going to work.
5. Your function doesn't insert anything, it updates a year's data for a given sea level, which is silly, but I guess that's what you want to do.

All in all, you might want something like

```
import sqlite3

import pandas as pd

sea_level_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\SeaLevel.csv", skiprows=3)
conn = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\slaye\OneDrive\Desktop\sqlite\db\z.db")
sea_level_df.to_sql('v', conn)


def update_sea_level(year, sea_level):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE v SET YEAR = ? WHERE SEA_LEVEL = ?", (year, sea_level))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: now it says 
```
OperationalError: no such column: SEA_LEVEL``` even though I'm literally looking at it in DB browser and it's there in that table.

Comment: Are you sure the capitalization is correct? And that you're looking at the right file, etc.?